# How return type annotation change behavior of scala mixin in Twitter's Effective Scala

Tags: scala, mixins

I have a very hard time understanding the following explanation from Twitter's Effective Scala https://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/:

> While Scala allows these to be omitted, such annotations provide good documentation: this is especially important for public methods. Where a method is not exposed and its return type obvious, omit them. This is especially important when instantiating objects with mixins as the scala compiler creates singleton types for these. For example, make in:

```
trait Service
def make() = new Service {
  def getId = 123
}
```

> does not have a return type of Service; the compiler creates the refinement type Object with Service{def getId: Int}. Instead use an explicit annotation:

```
def make(): Service = new Service{}
```

> Now the author is free to mix in more traits without changing the public type of make, making it easier to manage backwards compatibility.

I am trying to understand how return type annotation here helps development with backward compatibility. Can anyone demonstrate with a concrete code example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually really simple:

If you *explicitly* annotate the return type, the return type will forever what you said it would be.

If you *don't* annotate the return type, the return type will be inferred to whatever the type of the right-hand-side may be now.

So, whenever the type of the right-hand-side changes, in the first case, the return type will stay the same, in the second case, the return type will change, and thus (potentially) break existing users.

In this *particular* case, as mentioned, the return types in the first and second example are actually not the same:

```scala
def make(): Service = new Service {
  def getId = 123
}
```

The return type of `make()` is `Service`.

```scala
def make() = new Service {
  def getId = 123
}
```

The return type of `make()` is `Object with Service`.

If you now make a small change to your method, like e.g. extracting that method into a common `trait`:

```scala
trait IdGetter {
  def getId = 123
}
```

and Refactoring your code to use that trait:

```scala
def make(): Service = new Service with IdGetter {}
```

Now, in this case, the return type is *still* `Service`.

But in this case:

```scala
def make() = new Service with IdGetter {}
```

The return type is now `Object with Service with IdGetter`.

So, the return type has changed due to something which *should* have been a simple *Extract Method Refactoring* that is completely invisible to the user, but actually breaks downstream dependencies.